# make a default password for password textboxes that can't be reproduced by the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords

Is it possible to set a password textbox text to text that the user could not reproduce on their end?

Like are there special characters that can only be set from the server?

For instance, one way to do this would be to use javascript to prevent typing of *'s, and to set the textbox text to be all *'s.  But that's hacky.

The motivation is to be able to tell on the server if the user changed the password at all, but not to restrict them from having a password of all *'s, for instance.

Comment: So when the user type abc123 in the passfield it will (if you somehow make it a textbox) appear as something else ?

Comment: no, it starts as gobbledygook, like arrow, tab, linefeed, etc., then the user starts typing their allowed characters.

Comment: Like Lotus used to do in Notes? While typing your password it would show various characters/images in the password textbox.

Comment: Okay I officially don't get it. Why are you asking this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? I don't understand why you'd want to assign a user a password that they couldn't type.

Comment: Not familiar with Lotus.  The behavior of masking is fine, but I just wanted to be able to provide a password that the user couldn't reproduce by say deleting a character and then typing the same one.  Like to be able to tell ON the server if the user made changes.

Comment: @Chuck: , tony, goal is to not restrict them from having *regular* character passwords, but to be able to tell if they changed the password text in any way.

Comment: Okay. Is comparing the password that is submitted to the one stored for the user not working somehow? Your edit is helping, and perhaps I'm missing something, but I still don't see what your goal is. What's your use case? Is this a UI where the user is purposefully changing the password and you are trying to determine if they did indeed make a change?

Comment: @Chuck:  there are two problems 1) the user may accidentally change the (default) password by deleting / typing a character.  It should only change if they highlight the whole thing and change it.  2) The user may purposefully change the password by deleting a character.  But they don't realize that the password sent to them is in fact a dummy password.  (It is generally bad to expose the password, even if masked, as it can be viewn via javascript)

Comment: You don't have a confirmation box where they have to retype (and thereby verify) any password changes? A UI where the user can "accidentally" do anything is a poor one.

Comment: @Chuck: agreed.  A password strength indicator would also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, I don't think that is possible.

**Edit**

Why don't you use something as the default password which does not follow your rules for password length, allowed characters etc.? (Even if you allow all characters, allowing one-character passwords is not really an option, is it?)

Comment: I want to provide a default password, and save it only if the user changes the password.  But I don't want to restrict them from using any passwords.

Comment: Because I don't actually know the password rules.  It's a 3rd party thing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that is it impossible to specify a character that a user could not enter by themselves; however, it can be extremely difficult for the average user to enter certain characters.

In more detail; using a standard US 104-key keyboard in Windows, it is possible to enter Unicode character codes by holding Alt and typing the character code using the numpad keys. So, someone could enter a character that does not appear on the keyboard and cannot be typed with a combination of modifier and letter keys. 99% of computer users on the planet do not know this is possible, and even the remaining 1% would probably have to look up the code for a particular non-standard character.

Now, other languages which use the Latin characters, but with accent marks and other modifications, have easier-to-access modifier key combinations, allowing a user to type accented letters much like English speakers would use capital letters. Obviously, users in regions using different character sets have keyboards that can type very esoteric-seeming symbols with a single keypress. A user in one of those cultures would have much easier access to characters that are difficult for US 104-key users.

So, it is impossible to specify a character in the Unicode codepage from code, that could not be reproduced by a user on their keyboard. However, they'd have to know exactly which character was being used, and its Unicode code, in order to reproduce it.

Comment: not entirely impossible as you can restrict it to some extent in the javascript.  But I see what your saying, thanks.

Comment: You can also disable JavaScript.

Comment: That's true but if that's the case the page shouldn't work anyway :-P.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the TAB character (that is "\t"). But I'm sure there's a better way to do whatever it is that you're trying to do.

## edit

I think I understand what you are asking for now.

This ought to do what you want. It is javascript but it's real simple.

```
<input type="password" name="userpass" value="          " onfocus="if(this.pwclick == undefined){ this.default = this.value; this.value=''; this.pwclick = 1;}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = this.default;this.pwclick = undefined;}" />
```

Then on the backend just do the following and it will cause the javascript to be compatible even if the user has javascript turned off.

```
if(userpass.Trim().Length > 0{
  # actions to change the user's password
}
```

Comment: Tab? Pasting one in is trivial. I wish I could think of what they were trying to do. Frankly puzzled..

Comment: I know, I know. -- Perhaps..... he wants to set a variable in the database to untypable characters for each user that would behave as a salt in a way that would get concatenated with the user's password. I dunno.

Comment: Nope, the goal here was to not have to write special javascript to make it so if the user changes the password field the first time, it should clear it, but if he/she changes it subsequent times (before submitting it) it will not clear the field.  Also, to not disallow the default password of '****' say.   My goals can be met with more work, but it would be a lot easier if there was a way to set it with special characters that couldn't be assigned from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another hidden field that is intialized with the same text as you intialize the password text box.  Then if they are still the same when they submit it, give them an error.